# Should Node.js and MongoDB be in different pods?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

I am trying to host a simple Node.js app connected to MongoDB, I look on the web, I've found 2 different methods and some guides to do so:

1. Different pods:

   - [Example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/nodesjs-mongodb) from the official Kubernetes documentation.
   - [Example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-a-mean-stack-on-google-cloud-platform-with-kubernetes-149ca81c2b5d) from the official Google Cloud Platform documentation.
2. Same pod:

   - [Example](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/kubernetes-how-to-run-a-node-js-application-which-accesses-mongo-database-where-both-are-running-in-containers-in-a-single-pod/) from the official IBM documentation.

This confused me a bit, which is the best practise to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put them in different pods.

Being in different pods you can then scale up the number of replicas of the web application part to as many instances as you need and you will still have the one instance of MongoDB.

If you had them in the same pod, you wouldn't be able to scale up to multiple instances as each replica would have its own MongoDB instance and thus separate data. If doing data updates to MongoDB from the web application, that would cause all sorts of problems as subsequent requests could hit a difference instance and so see different data.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you clarify then, what is the point of the 2nd tutorial I linked, and what is the point of this idea of "MongoDB StatefulSets/ReplicaSets"? http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html It sounds like I should be replicating my MongoDB too?

Comment: How you scale up databases is never as simple as creating more instances of them. If you have multiple instances of a database talking to same data files in a persistent volume, they would usually just corrupt the data for each other. Scaling databases takes a lot more work than just increase replicas. So there is no good reason to stick a database in the same pod as the web application.

Comment: When in the same pod you can actually create subtle problems even when a single instance. This is because in a rolling deployment, a new instance will be created before stopping the old. Thus have problem of multiple writers to data file again. Database should always be separate and a deployment strategy used where you only ever have one instance of the database running at a time.

Comment: So for Kubernetes Deployment objects, if a database, you always want to have single instance and use Recreate deployment strategy. Don't use a RollingUpdate. You can use RollingUpdate for web application front end if stateless, but if it has persistent volumes attached, need to be careful there as well depending on type of persistent volume.

Comment: So it sounds like the 2nd tutorial I linked in the question is a bad idea all around. What is the point of then, of MongoDB StatefulSets as seen here: http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html ?

Comment: In a StatefullSet, you would still have MongoDB in a separate pod if wanted to do that. Among other things, what StatefullSet does is allow you to control the order pods are started up. Thus can ensure database is running before start front end that requires it.

Comment: In that example though you will see though that it isn't as simple as scaling up number of instances. Each MongoDB instance is told about the others so they can synchronise data. I haven't looked in detail at example, but I doubt they simply share same persistent volume and otherwise started as if in isolation.

Comment: This is what I mean about scaling of database needing to be done in special ways.

Comment: MongoDB replica sets are also mentioned here https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/running-mongodb-as-a-microservice-with-docker-and-kubernetes, but it seems like new StatefulSets should be used instead of ReplicaSets. I was confused because I thought more ReplicaSets/StatefulSets = scaling up the number of instances, but you clarified that's not the case and that it needs to be done in "special ways". I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: +1. StatefulSets are more appropriate for running databases and other stateful applications because they come with their own storage and have some nice guarantees. It's always recommended to have separate pods for separately updatable components, keeping in line with 12-factor microservice-based architecture.

Comment: As with any deployment, you still need to create a persistent volume claim for what you are using with a deployment under a StatefulSet. That should be no different to a normal deployment. So not sure what you mean by they come with their own storage.